# real analytic interpolation

Tags: real-analysis

Given monotonic sequence $x_n$ of reals. Does there exist a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ and real-analytic function $f$ on $(1;+\infty)$ such that $f(n_k)=x_{n_k}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: I have tried formal series $$
 f(s) = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cdot\frac{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(s-i_k)}{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(i_n-i_k)}
 $$ where $a_n$ could be determined by induction from equations $f(i_k)=x_{i_k}$.

Answer (score 0):

- If $x_n\to \infty$, take $|x_{n_k}|> k^2$ $$h(z) =\prod_k (1-\frac{z}{x_{n_k}}), \qquad h_m(z)=\frac1{1-\frac{z}{x_{n_m}}}$$ are entire and uniformly bounded by $\prod_k (1+\frac{|z|}{|x_{n_k}|})$, take $g(z)$ entire [growing fast enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Growth) on the real axis such that $$|\frac{f(x_{n_m})}{h_m(x_{n_m})g(x_{n_m})} |\le 1/m^2$$ then $$g(z)\sum_m \frac{f(x_{n_m})}{h_m(x_{n_m})g(x_{n_m})} h_m(z)$$ converges locally uniformly thus it is entire
- If $x_n$ is bounded, if there exists a function analytic at $a=\sup x_n$ agreeing with $f(x_n)$ then it is the only one, and it is given by the Taylor series at $a$ which is found from the differences of the $f(x_n)$.

Comment: sorry, but $h_m(x_{n_m})$ is not defined